# How to refer an instanced attribute from another class

Tags: python-3.x, class, attributes, instance

I want to use an instance attribute (in this case the first name of a user, "Juan") in a different class to use it as a prompt to print all its privileges.

The solution I've done is to delete "self.first_name" in the line of code. 
So instead of

```py
print("Since your an admin," + self.first_name + ", you have the following privileges: ")
```

It now becomes

```py
print("Since your an admin, you have the following privileges: ")
```

which is still okay but without it referring to the instance attribute.

The question is how can I forgo with my initial idea of including "Juan" in the prompt? and what changes should I implement in order to use that line of code?

```py
# Snippet of the Code
class Privileges:
    """Make a Privilege Object for each specific user"""
    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the privileges attributes"""
        self.privileges = ["can delete posts", "can ban user", "can add post"]

    def show_privileges(self):
        """Print all the privileges of the admin"""
        print("Since your an admin," + self.first_name + ", you have the following privileges: ")
        for privilege in self.privileges:
            print("You " + privilege + ".")


class Admin(User):
    """Make an Admin User and Inherit attributes from class "User" """
    def __init__(self, first_name,  last_name, age, gender):
        super().__init__(first_name, last_name, age, gender)
        self.privileges = Privileges()


user_1 = Admin("juan", "dela cruz", 5, "male")
user_1.privileges.show_privileges()
```

========================================================================
The intended output is:

```py
Since your an admin, Juan, You have the following privileges: 
You can delete posts.
You can ban user.
You can add post.
```

Error Message:

```
    print("Since your an admin," + self.first_name + ", you have the following privileges: ")
    AttributeError: 'Privileges' object has no attribute 'first_name'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to directly add the parent object's name, since multiple references to same privilege may exist. You'll need to pass the user's name to the Privilege instance.

You can do so in the constructor, which will tie the privilege to a single user. The alternative is passing the name into `show_privileges`. This is the more generalized approach, although it does require more typing since you have to pass it every time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your answer! :D Just started using python recently

```py
# Corrected Code
class Privileges:
    """Make a Privilege Class"""
    def __init__(self, first_name):
        """Initialize the privileges attributes"""
        self.privileges = ["can delete posts", "can ban user", "can add post"]
        self.first_name = first_name # 2. Added this line as well

    def show_privileges(self):
        """Print all the privileges of the admin"""
        print("Since your an admin, " + self.first_name + ", you have the following privileges: ")
        for privilege in self.privileges:
            print("You " + privilege + ".")


class Admin(User):
    """Make an Admin User and Inherit attributes from class "User" """
    def __init__(self, first_name,  last_name, age, gender):
        super().__init__(first_name, last_name, age, gender)
        self.privileges = Privileges(self.first_name)  # 1. Passed the value of the first name here


user_1 = Admin("Juan", "dela cruz", 33, "male")
user_1.privileges.show_privileges()
```